# Python Selenium file stops uploading when trying to read upload status from site

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to a site. Everything is fine, but at the moment selenium tries to read data from tag, uploading suddenly stops.

The uploading progress bar html code is:

```
<div id="progressbar1" class="progressbar">
   <div id="progresspercent1" class="progresspercent">5%</div>
</div>
```

and my code is:

```
bar_id = "progresspercent1"
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, bar_id)))
print("PERCENT:" + driver.find_element(By.XPATH, bar_id).text)
```

I also tried accessing this tag:

```
<tr id="uploadfile1" title="Upload" uploadrowid="1" status="cancel">
</tr>
```

And I used its "status" attribute to check if the file is uploading or not, but I had the same problem again. And I also tried using `get_attribute('innerHTML')` method (for progress bar) but that doesn't work too.

EDIT:
This is how I start uploading:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "menu_upload").click()
frame = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="uploader1"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)  
driver.find_element(By.ID,"fileupload").send_keys(<File Address>)
```

The first line opens the upload box frame. I just switch to the frame and then try to upload the file using the last line.

And right now I'm not doing anything after printing the percent. Later on I might create a loop to print the percent and when the file was uploaded, close the webdriver.

Comment: Could you please share a code where we can see how you start the upload and what are you doing after printing the percent?

Comment: @EugenyOkulik I just edited the question. Can you please check it once more?

Comment: And what happens if you don't try to get the status? The window stays opened and the upload proceeds? Looks like it needs some experiments. I can find some place for that but can you share the link?

Comment: @EugenyOkulik yup it works perfectly when I don't try to get the status. The site is picofile.com which doesn't support english, but you can try your browser translator.